# Installing an app with Node fails miserably - npm ERR! fetch failed

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install and test an app that uses NodeJS.

The instruction simply say to run these commands...

```
git clone https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat.git

cd lets-chat

npm install

npm start
```

When I run `npn install` things go really bad and I see like 100 error messages in my console!

```
npm WARN engine mongoose-validate@0.0.5: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
|


> node-stringprep@0.7.0 install E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat\node_mo
dules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-stringprep@0.7.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-stringprep@0.7.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-stringprep package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-stringprep
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.5
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/-/ipaddr.js-0.1.8.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/hike/-/hike-1.0.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/onecolor/-/onecolor-2.5.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss/-/postcss-4.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-tools/-/fs-tools-0.2.11.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-extra/-/fs-extra-0.14.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/mimoza/-/mimoza-0.3.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/-/nan-1.6.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore/-/configstore-0.3.2.tgz
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat\node_modules\grunt-bower\node_modules\bower\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream\bench\dropper.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat\node_modules\grunt-bower\node_modules\bower\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream\bench\dropper.js
npm ERR! fstream_path E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat\node_modules\grunt-bower\node_modules\bower\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream\bench\dropper.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/engine.io-parser/-/engine.io-parser-1.2.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/benchmark/-/benchmark-1.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv/-/iconv-2.1.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-2.11.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/-/ipaddr.js-0.1.8.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/hike/-/hike-1.0.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/onecolor/-/onecolor-2.5.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss/-/postcss-4.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-tools/-/fs-tools-0.2.11.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-extra/-/fs-extra-0.14.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/mimoza/-/mimoza-0.3.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/-/nan-1.6.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/configstore/-/configstore-0.3.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/engine.io-parser/-/engine.io-parser-1.2.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/benchmark/-/benchmark-1.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv/-/iconv-2.1.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-2.11.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/hike/-/hike-1.0.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/onecolor/-/onecolor-2.5.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss/-/postcss-4.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-tools/-/fs-tools-0.2.11.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/-/nan-1.6.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-extra/-/fs-extra-0.14.0.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.0.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.0.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing kerberos@0.0.9
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing kerberos@0.0.9
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/-/ipaddr.js-0.1.8.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/mimoza/-/mimoza-0.3.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/engine.io-parser/-/engine.io-parser-1.2.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/benchmark/-/benchmark-1.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv/-/iconv-2.1.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-2.11.1.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing request@2.53.0
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     E:\Server\htdocs\projects\lets-chat\lets-chat\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I see the first part of the error messages is this complaining about a Windows component missing.  I should have that but I will fix that....

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.
```

However the bulk of the errors are related to `NODE`

How can I fix these?

Comment: The error you call out is the key one . One of the dependencies is a native module and needs to get compiled.  Fix that, and all the other stuff should go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you install VS that should do it.

I should also add that you might have issues getting this thing to run in Windows. Maybe consider using docker or one of the other deployment options.

Source: I'm one of the authors of Let's Chat.